# Meteor.js collection remove error: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to remove an object from a collection but am encountering this error:

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run
>   very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial
>   [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

Here is my code:

```
Activities = new Mongo.Collection("activities");    

// some code

Template.weekday.events({

     'click .delete_activity': function(event) {
         Activities.remove({day: this.valueOf()});
     }

});
```

Interestingly enough, it works when I do instead:

```
'click .delete_activity': function(event) {
     var activity = Activities.findOne({day: this.valueOf()});
     Activities.remove(activity._id);
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why this is occuring? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions here:

1. The first is "why I am seeing that message about prototypes?"
2. The second is about "why my code is throwing an error?"

Let me start by the first one. The reason you're seeing that message is because Meteor is messing around with the original `Error` object prototype when you're using Firefox:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor/errors.js#L16

About the second question. The error is thrown, because for security in your client code, you can only remove elements from collections by their ids. You can only do things like:

```
Activities.remove({day: this.valueOf()});
```

server side. This can be easily worked around by fetching the required elements first and then remove them by ids, so exactly the same way you did in your example.

Comment: It was an error. Firefox also printed out `Error` on the next line and the object was not removed from the database.

Comment: Cool, so it was an error in your code, which you need to fix. But your question was about the "warning" message right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: That "warning" message was an error message. I changed the code like above and all error messages were gone. I wondering if there is a reason for why it caused an error.

Comment: There may be different reasons why you're getting an error while removing an object from database. You probably need to provide more information to get an answer that it satisfactory. And make sure to explain in details what exactly you're asking about.